# Save a variable from a function to reuse when it loops

Tags: python

I just started to learn python yesterday so complete noob. I have about 10 hours javascript experience to but had to switch since I'm learning Python in college. I decided to try make a program by myself since I learn a lot better doing that instead of countless videos.

The major problem I'm having is saving my variable of balance. When I win or lose the balance just restarts at 2000. I think that's probably because of the variable `balance = 2000` but if I don't define it, it doesn't work. I know it's not anything important but I want to learn where I'm going wrong.

If anyone can help me that would be much appreciated. Also I know the codes a mess but will try make it better later.

```
global balance
name = input ("Please Enter Your Name: ")
password = input ("Please Make A Password: ")

def playgame():
 balance = 2000
 yesOrNo = input("Would You Like To Put A Bet on Y/N?; ")
 if yesOrNo == "y":
  howBigABet = int(input("How Much Would You like to bet?: "))
  if howBigABet <= balance:
     pickNumber = int(input("Please PicK A Number: "))
     from random import randint
     value = randint(0, 1)
     print(value)
     if pickNumber == value:
           print(value)
           balance = balance + howBigABet * 2
           print("you won " + str(howBigABet * 2))
           print(balance)
           playgame()
     else:
      print ("Sorry Wrong Number")
      balance = balance - howBigABet
      print("your new balance is: " + str(balance))
      playgame()
  if balance <= 200:
   print("You Are Low on Cash Top up?")
  elif balance <= 0:
   print("You Are Out Of cash " + name + " Top Up ")
   playgame()

 else:
    print("Sorry You Dont Have Enough Money")

print("Hello " + name)
passwordAttempted = input("Please Enter Your Password: ")

if passwordAttempted == password:
    print("Welcome " + name)
    playgame()
else:
    print ("Wrong Password " + name + " !")
```

Comment: What you're missing is a loop, or persisting the value to an external source. When the program ends, all data is cleared. You can do a loop inside the program, though (`while` or `for` loops could both work), and as long as you first define the variable outside the loop it'll remember changes to the balance as long as the program runs.

Comment: What do you mean by: `saving my balance variable`?

Comment: @quamrana sorry I edited my post to explain what I meant. Basically Trying to make a betting game as a way to learn python. So need the balance to update. Later I'm going to try and put teams with different stats to bet on.

Comment: @nathainiel Thank you will try a for loop.

Comment: Your code ***is a mess***, a big one. I strongly suggest you stop writing code for a few minutes and read (and start following) the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `balance` is local to the function `playgame()` every time the function is called, the variable will be reset. You can fix this problem a couple of ways. You can make `balance` a global variable, or you can add a loop where the function doesn't return after one execution. The second example I gave would look something like this:

```
global balance
name = input ("Please Enter Your Name: ")
password = input ("Please Make A Password: ")





def playgame():
    balance = 2000
    yesOrNo = input("Would You Like To Put A Bet on Y/N?; ")
    while yesOrNo == "y":
        howBigABet = int(input("How Much Would You like to bet?: "))
        if howBigABet <= balance:
            pickNumber = int(input("Please PicK A Number: "))
            from random import randint
            value = randint(0, 1)
            print(value)
            if pickNumber == value:
                print(value)
                balance = balance + howBigABet * 2
                print("you won " + str(howBigABet * 2))
                print(balance)
                yesOrNo = input("Would You Like To Put A Bet on Y/N?; ")
                continue


            else:
                print ("Sorry Wrong Number")
                balance = balance - howBigABet
                print("your new balance is: " + str(balance))
                yesOrNo = input("Would You Like To Put A Bet on Y/N?; ")
                continue
        if balance <= 200:
            print("You Are Low on Cash Top up?")
        elif balance <= 0:
            print("You Are Out Of cash " + name + " Top Up ")
            yesOrNo = input("Would You Like To Put A Bet on Y/N?; ")
            continue
        else:
            print("Sorry You Dont Have Enough Money")


print("Hello " + name)
passwordAttempted = input("Please Enter Your Password: ")


if passwordAttempted == password:
    print("Welcome " + name)
    playgame()
else:
    print ("Wrong Password " + name + " !")
```

Comment: Legend that worked was a bit confused how to add the loop. Wouldn't have guessed to Add it to yesOrNo variable. but now I have seen it, it clicks. Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass `balance` as an argument, to your `playgame` function

like this

```py
def playgame(balance=2000):
    yesOrNo = input("Would You Like To Put A Bet on Y/N?; ")
    ...
```

And than just pass, the new balance to all the playgame calls

But a much better way than using a recurent function would be a while loop

```py
name = input ("Please Enter Your Name: ")
password = input ("Please Make A Password: ")


def playgame(balance=2000):
 yesOrNo = input("Would You Like To Put A Bet on Y/N?; ")
 if yesOrNo == "y":
  howBigABet = int(input("How Much Would You like to bet?: "))
  if howBigABet <= balance:
     pickNumber = int(input("Please PicK A Number: "))
     from random import randint
     value = randint(0, 1)
     print(value)
     if pickNumber == value:
           print(value)
           balance = balance + howBigABet * 2
           print("you won " + str(howBigABet * 2))
           print(balance)
           return balance


     else:
      print ("Sorry Wrong Number")
      balance = balance - howBigABet
      print("your new balance is: " + str(balance))
      return balance
  if balance <= 200:
   print("You Are Low on Cash Top up?")
  elif balance <= 0:
   print("You Are Out Of cash " + name + " Top Up ")
   return balance

 else:
    print("Sorry You Dont Have Enough Money")


print("Hello " + name)
passwordAttempted = input("Please Enter Your Password: ")


if passwordAttempted == password:
    print("Welcome " + name)
    balance = playgame()
    while input("You want to play again? Y/N").lower() == "y": 
        balance = playgame(balance)
else:
    print ("Wrong Password " + name + " !")
```

Please note, that this code is not tested and may not work how you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help. will remember I can do that. I tried just balance as a parameter before but didn't add the = 2000  at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing `playgame` does is set your balance to 2000, so it's always going to be 2000 at the beginning of a game. This is happening because you restart a new game by calling `playgame()` *from within `playgame`.* This is called recursion. It's a powerful tool that has a lot of uses, but this is probably not the best use of it. Among other things, when a game ends, it's going to return to where it was in the previous game, and pick up executing the next statement after `playgame()`. (You don't have anything like that in your current code, but the moment you do, you'll get confused. In short, `playgame()` is not a simple "go back to the beginning" command.)

So one way to address this is to change the main structure of your function to a loop. After `balance = 2000` add:

```
while True:
```

and indent the rest of the function under that statement.

Wherever you have `playgame()` within the `playgame` function, change it to `continue`. This will cause the program to go back to the beginning of the `while` loop.

Since `balance = 2000` is not within the loop, it will be executed once and will not be re-executed for subsequent games.

Another way to solve the problem (keeping the recursion) is to move the initialization of `balance` outside the loop, say to right after you ask for the user's name and password. In the `playgame` function, replace `balance = 2000` with `global balance`. This way, the variable is not local to the function and will retain its value from call to call.

Finally, you could make the game a class rather than a standalone function. This way, `balance` can be an attribute of the object rather than a local variable to your function, but still not a global. (Global variables are generally a bad idea, especially as your code gets more complex, because they make it difficult to keep track of every piece of the data the function uses to do its job.) This is probably the best way to do it long-term, but you'll need to learn a bit more about programming before you tackle that.

Comment: Thank you, Yeah I will avoid classes at the moment . I'm hoping to learn about them soon  haha.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on loops since you said you are new to python, you can initiate the `balance` variable outside the function, and in a loop, you can ask for user input and call the function. Based on the input, you can rerun the function or exit and display balance.

One way would be, to modify you `if-else` loop for `yesOrNo` and add an elif (say `elif yesOrNo=='end'`), then `break` the loop and display `balance`.